# How to initialize listview inside fragment in activity

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-adapter

I am new to android. I am trying to initialize listview in fragment using a custom adapter but I have problem with using the custom adapter constructor.

Here is my custom adapter code.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre())
    {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0, genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

and here is my fragment activty code.

```
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private Custom_Adapter_Fragment adapter2;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


   // ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

  // adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), movieList);
  //
   // adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), movieList);
    adapter2 = new Custom_Adapter_Fragment(movieList,getContext());




}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news,null);
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);



    return view;
}
private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

}

here is my logcat

```
03-13 19:56:16.036 17211-17211/com.example.krunal.anamika E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.krunal.anamika, PID: 17211
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.example.krunal.anamika.fragments.News.onCreateView(News.java:125)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2058)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1374)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5905)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:807)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:601)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:562)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:791)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.i
```

I know that the problem is in custom adapter constructor.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the constructor. What is line 125 of onCreateView?

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`?? Either `adapter` is null because it's commented out. Or your `findViewById` is returning null because your news.xml doesn't have `android.R.id.list`

Comment: when i debug it its gone crash on constructor.? and at line 125 code is like this   AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);        which is a another class which is i used

Comment: Have you added AppController to your Android manifest as an Application?

Comment: yaa i have added it, accually i dont know what is the use of that class. but i added  it i downloaded it from androidhive

Comment: Can you please use the edit link between the comments here and your question to add the manifest file? You can't just download the AppController file and have it work immediately.

Comment: Thanks man for your help i resolve error now. thanks a lot cricket_007

Comment: Glad to hear it. Not exactly sure what the problem was, but you're welcome to answer your own questions to let others know the solution if they happen to find this post.

Comment: yaa man actually i forget to declare appcontroller in manifest file. and also not assigned internet permission in manifest file.